# Does surveymonkey api return the unique ID associated with their unique id specifications?

Tags: api, surveymonkey

Can anyone tell me if they are know for certain whether or not survey monkey's api has the ability to return the unique ID associated with their designated unique id specifications:
http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Can-I-track-respondents-using-a-unique-ID

It states the following regarding viewing this in the aforementioned link:

> When these results come back on the survey, that custom ID of "00001"
>   appears in the **Custom Value** field in the **Analyze > Browse Responses**
>   section.

However I cannot find any mention of this data being returned from their API in the API documentation:
https://developer.surveymonkey.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be retrieved by sending 'custom_id' as a requested field to 'get_respondent_list':

https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_respondent_list

It will then be in the 'custom_id' field in the respondent's dictionary.